# Mustache.js with preloaded template

Tags: javascript, mustache

I use mustache.js in my product and it works like a charm. But it became necessary to to apply mustache to my index page. e.g.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>{{title}}</title>
      ....
```

as far i know, the only way to render is Mustache.render(tpl,view) and tpl should be a string. `$('html').html(Mustache.render($('html').html(), view))` looks very ugly.

Is there an easy way out? Or i should invent bycicle)?

Comment: Is it a web application or a webpage? Generally you should not place the template as real html and load if from there because the browser could modify it making you template invalid. So either provide it as precompiled script that you load or wrap it into something like `<script type="text/x-template" class='tpl-main'> <div>{{your.template}}</div></script>`.

Comment: Are you serving the index page as a static file? If you have any sort of server-side language (e.g. Python, Ruby, PHP, ...), there's probably an implementation of Mustache for whatever you're using, and it would probably be best to put the code for generating the index page on the server side. Using a Mustache template as the actual served HTML seems like bad practice and will degrade poorly (e.g. if the user doesn't have Javascript enabled) even if you can get it to work.

Comment: @t.niese It is a web app. I use m.js for loading content in <body>. But what to do with <head>?

Comment: @svk no, i have no backend.

Comment: What are the elements in the `head` that will change, just the title?

Comment: @t.niese title, desc, maybe tags. Also maybe some other text constants in bottom of the page (e.g. i load content in <body><section..., and i have static <footer>)

Comment: hm...I've remembered :contains selector in jQuery. What do you think about `$(':contains("{{")')` ? But there are problem that it returns a tree. E.g.: if h1 contains {{ than html, body, h1 are returned.

Answer (score 0):

@sroes suggested me a jQuery function http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/
Author promisses: "only text content will be modified, leaving all tags and attributes untouched".

#### How to use in my case?

Its simple:

```
$('html *').replaceText(/{{([^}]+)}}/, function(fullMatch, key) {
    return key;
}, true);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/4nvNy/
Thank @sroes alot!